# Find Node by Attribute (XML) in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I am trying to target a node(s) based on an attribute it contains. I have looked around and apparently `XML.Node.(@attribute == "desired attribute")` is supposed to return all nodes with that specific value but for some reason it doesn't for me. It also doesn't work with `XML.Node.(@attribute != "desired attribute")`. It's like it doesn't recognize that the values are the same, or arn't. However, if I just do `XML.Node` it returns all of the nodes of that type. This is my code (in just the one class):

```
package  
{
    import net.flashpunk.Entity;
    import net.flashpunk.FP;
    import net.flashpunk.graphics.Graphiclist;
    import net.flashpunk.graphics.Tilemap;
    import net.flashpunk.masks.Grid;
    import net.flashpunk.World;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Owen 
     */
    public class Map extends Entity 
    {
        public var layer_background:Tilemap;
        public var layer_forground:Tilemap;

        public var collisionMap:Grid;

        public var player:Player;

        public function Map()
        {

        }

        public function loadMap(xmlData:Class, spawn:int = 0):void
        {
            var mapXML:XML = FP.getXML(xmlData);
            // Loading the background from XML
            layer_background = new Tilemap(Assets.TILEMAP, mapXML.@width, mapXML.@height, Constants.TILE_WIDTH, Constants.TILE_HEIGHT);
            layer_background.loadFromString(mapXML.Background);

            // Loading the forground from XML
            layer_forground = new Tilemap(Assets.TILEMAP, mapXML.@width, mapXML.@height, Constants.TILE_WIDTH, Constants.TILE_HEIGHT);
            layer_forground.loadFromString(mapXML.Forground);

            // Loading the collision map from XML
            collisionMap = new Grid(mapXML.@width, mapXML.@height, Constants.TILE_WIDTH, Constants.TILE_HEIGHT);
            collisionMap.loadFromString(mapXML.Collision);

            // Adding the player, getting location and data from XML
            player = new Player;

            var spawnNode = mapXML.Misc.Spawn.(@direction == "down");
            trace("spawnNode = " + spawnNode);

            // Nevermind this
            player.setLoc(1, 2);
            player.setDir("down");

            // Tracing the "Spawn" nodes, not attribute specific
            trace(" Not attribute specific: " + mapXML.Misc.Spawn);
            // This doesn't trace anything
            trace(" == with int (nothing traces): " + mapXML.Misc.Spawn.(@entrance == 0));

            // Same thing if we try with a string
            trace(" == with string: " + mapXML.Misc.Door.(@desLevel == "level1"));

            // This however works
            trace(" This works: " + mapXML.Misc.Door.@desLevel);

            graphic = new Graphiclist(layer_background, layer_forground);
        }





    }

}
```

And this is the XML (It a .oel, which is just an xml in disguise)

```
<level width="640" height="480">
  <Collision exportMode="Bitstring">11011111111111111111
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000000000001
10000000000011100001
10000000000010100001
10000000000000100001
10000000000010100001
11111111111110111111</Collision>
  <Background tileset="tileset" exportMode="CSV">32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,4,4,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,20,33,33,5,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,20,33,33,33,5,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,20,33,33,33,5,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,21,21,21,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,4,4,4,4,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,20,33,33,33,33,5,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,20,33,33,33,33,33,5,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,21,21,21,21,21,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32
32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32</Background>
  <Forground tileset="tileset" exportMode="CSV">2,0,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,36,17,37,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,16,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,35,-1,16,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
16,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,16,-1,-1,-1,-1,1
18,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,19,-1,18,17,17,17,17,19</Forground>
  <Entities />
  <Misc>
    <Door id="0" x="64" y="0" desLevel="&quot;level1&quot;" desSpawn="0" />
    <Spawn id="1" x="64" y="32" entrance="0" direction="&quot;down&quot;" />
    <Door id="2" x="384" y="384" desLevel="&quot;level2&quot;" desSpawn="0" />
    <Spawn id="3" x="352" y="384" entrance="1" direction="&quot;left&quot;" />
  </Misc>
</level>
```

I'm also using Flashpunk in my game, so that's where some if the imports are coming from. I'm using Ogmo Editor, works well with FlashPunk, to create and export the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `mapXML.Misc.Spawn.(@entrance == 0)` is returning no value? I've setup an identical system and it does, but it does not trace out..

Try one of these two commands and see if you are still getting nothing.

```
trace("length:", mapXML.Misc.Spawn.(@entrance == 0).length());
trace("xml":, mapXML.Misc.Spawn.(@entrance == 0).toXMLString());
```

Though be absolutely sure your XML is setup perfectly. As if there is not a Spawn node that does not have a entrance attribute it will throw an error. You can always use below to be safe.

```
mapXML.Misc.Spawn.(attribute('entrance') == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

it works, but not as it you expect.

This code `mapXML.Misc.Spawn.(@entrance == 0)` returns only value and children nodes of founded node. So in your cases it will be empty.
For example `trace(mapXML.Collision.(@exportMode=="Bitstring"))` will return `1101...`.

I don't how to find node with E4X syntax, but you can do this in another way. Something like that:

```
for each (var node:XML in mapXML.Misc.Spawn)
{
    if (node.@id == 0)
        return node;
}
```